# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline - Call a REST API after executing each stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have a Jenkins scripted pipeline with 6 stages. I need to call a REST api at the end of each stage to push the status of the stage to Cassandra DB. Is there an efficient way of doing this in Jenkins Pipeline?

Currently, I am calling a function at the end of each stage with the status. I have to write this piece of code in all stages even if the stage succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the shared library function, to write you code once and call it all over the pipeline eg. in diffent pipelines? Here is the link to the docs.  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries

Comment: I am looking at way to avoid calling the function at the end of each stage. This does not solve the problem.